# How to remove data from an index when indexing a view in Azure Search?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I index the view from my database. When I add an entry to the table, an entry is also added to the view. Index indexes new data. But when I delete this entry from the table in the index, it remains. How to set up a soft delete?
I read the documentation and it says it is necessary to add a field. Should I add it myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to remove deleted documents from your index, is by using the **SQL Integrated Change Detection** feature or by setting up a **Data Deletion Detection Policy** (Soft Delete).

If you choose the second option, then you have to create a soft-delete column in your view.
Then tell your datasource that it should track the soft-delete field:

[image]